# Laptop shutting down and has CPU temperature spikes

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

So I have a Predator PH315-51 laptop for 3 years. I usually change the thermal paste, clean it and reinstall windows every 3 months.

Yesterday my laptop just shut down while playing a game. Never had this problem, I didn't change/install anything except drivers (updates).

This morning I clean it, change thermal paste and reinstall windows. With a clean install, laptop fans + pad fans, only the PredatorSense app from acer and task manager, the idle was 50 degrees. If I open Chrome, just open, the temperature spikes at 90-95 degrees then coming back. Only the CPU, the GPU temperature is ok.

I assume the laptop shuts down when it reaches 100 degrees for safety reason, but the actual temperature is not 100. It's like the sensor is reading temperature as loading %.

Any idea why the laptop shuts down? maybe it's not the temperature and it's another problem, but I'm not so sure. Thank you!

Comment: The sensor is built into the processor. I can almost guarantee that there actually is a temperature issue

Comment: I did what I always did, unscrew the heatsink, clean the GPU/CPU and the heatsink from thermal paste, apply thermal paste on GPU/CPU, screw everything back the way it was. + clean the fans. Never had this problem. You can be right, but don't know what to do.

Comment: Laptops have extremely tight tolerances. The problem you describe, the simplest explanation, is a temperature issue

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: This is a wild stab in the dark here but have you oiled the bearings/bushes on the fans, they don't stay good forever on their own. (Many are sealed and can't be given additional lubrication) Can you check the fan-speed in any way? If it's dropped, you might need new fans. Possible indication is increased (or decreased) noise.

Comment: Also, #Facepalm, check you remembered to plug them in again the last time you reassembled the machine.

Comment: Check the cooling policy is set to high (fans on high not idle), after that maybe get one of those laptop cooling docks with fans inside to push more air through. The last resort would be to under-clock it to bring the core speeds down. Maybe go down in 5% increments until you reach a stable point.